# What happened to my green chili leaf?

Tags: indoors, chili

I recently planted a few Asian hot chilies. It is completely indoor and beside the window. They got morning sunlight. I watering them every other day.

In the last couple of days, I noticed a few leaves have this problem, the front site has a tiny white dot, and the backside has a kind of whitish spot.

I've no idea what it is, I tried to look at other solutions but none of them is similar to mine. Because of COVID19 I'm staying home and can't go to the store. If possible homemade solutions are welcome!

[image: chili frontside]

[image: chili backside]

Answer (score 1):

Has this plant been indoor all the time? It could look a bit like [Edema, or oedema](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/environmental/oedema.aspx) that is caused by overwatering. Try to let the soil dry out and only water them when it gets a bit sad. Does the new leaves also have this symptoms?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes it is indoor always, New leaves look fine. Okay, I'll less water them and see if works!